# React-Router-Dom not working properly. Its giving error related to hooks I have not even used in my project

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to use React-Router-Dom Version 6.12 in my Blog Project. My main purpose is to make navbar links active. I could have use a normal anchor tag but figured its the best way to learn new stuff. The code is as follows:

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
/* import of all the components */
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Login from './pages/Login/Login';

/* const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Navbar />,
    children: 
    [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />
      }
    ] 
  }
]) */

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/Account' element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I saw a tutorial on YouTube for 'How to use React-Router-Dom v6.12' and tried CreateBrowserRouter with RouterProvider as well. That also didn't worked.

Navbar.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const Navbar = () => {

    const [nav, setNav] = useState(false)

    const links = [
        {
            id: 1,
            link: '/',
            title: 'Home',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            link: '/About',
            title: 'About',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            link: '/Pages',
            title: 'Pages',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            link: '/Blog',
            title: 'Blog',
        },

    ]

  return (
    <div className='relative flex justify-between items-center w-full h-20 p-4 bg-white shadow-md md:px-10'>
        <div>
            <h1 className='font-title text-3xl md:text-4xl'>Personal Blog</h1>
        </div>
        <ul className='md:flex hidden'>
            {links.map(({id, link, title}) => (
                <li
                    key={id}
                    className='flex px-6 text-xl font-bold items-center cursor-pointer capitalize hover:scale-105 duration-300'
                >
                    <Link to={link}> {title}</Link>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <div className='md:flex hidden items-center cursor-pointer'>
            <Link to='/Account'><h1 className='text-xl font-bold'>My Account</h1></Link>
        </div>
        <div 
            className='flex md:hidden'
            onClick={() => setNav(!nav)}
        >
            {nav ? <FaTimes size={30} /> : <FaBars size={30} />}
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "heroicons": "^2.0.18",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

I am getting this error of React-Hooks which I have not even used in my project.
[Error Message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsmib.png)

I tried working with CreateBrowserRouter and RouterProvider as well. That didnt worked. I am not sure how to make it work.
I want to navigate to different pages through Navbar. I am not sure how to make it work. Been stuck at this issue for 3 days.

Comment: According to your package.json file you haven't specified `react-router-dom` as a project dependency. Is it even installed? Check by running `npm list react-router-dom` in the terminal in the root project directory. If it's not  installed, add it to the project by running `npm install -S react-router-dom@6`.

Comment: you have not installed react-router-dom first install it with command npm i react-router-dom and then run project to see output

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you should use hooks inside the Functional component. In NavBar component the hook is inside functional component. check inside Home and login component.